# How can I pass form variable to footer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to put the `= f.submit` portion of my form inside the footer partial, but am getting the error:

> NameError in Responses#new
>
> undefined local variable or method 'f' for `#<#Class<Class:0x00007fcd80439d10>:0x00007fcd804314d0>`

What changes would you recommend in my code examples below?

#### app/views/layouts/application.html.haml

```
%body
  %main
    = yield
  %footer
    = render partial: 'layouts/footer', locals: { f: f } # <-- this line errors
```

#### app/views/responses/new.html.haml

```
= form_for @response do |f|
  = f.text_field :answer
```

#### app/views/layouts/_footer.html.haml

```
= f.submit
```

Comment: why don't you use a `submit_tag` instead? it'll accomplish the same

Comment: Also, if you place the submit button outside of the form tag, then it won't actually submit the form. You will need to have some JS to submit the form for you, then. See my answer down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share elements like that you can use `content_for` and `yield`, like this:

```
# _footer.haml
= yield :footer_content
```

And then in your template file:

```
# new.haml
= form_for @object, id: 'form1' do |f|
  # form elements goes here

= content_for :footer_content do 
  %button{:onclick => "document.getElementById('form1').submit()"}
```

Because of the fact that the button is outside of the form you will need to add that custom JS to submit the form correctly.

Hope this helps.